# Ошибка Cannot declare class в Symfony 4 при создании своей bundle

Tags: php, symfony4

Пытаюсь создать свой bundle для многократного использования. Совершенно непредсказуемым образом вылетает ошибка:

```
Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\ICatcher\Builder\ControlPanel, because the name is already in use (1/1) FatalErrorException Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\ICatcher\Builder\ControlPanel, because the name is already in use in ControlPanel.php line 23
```

Причем если закомментить весь класс, обновить страницу, потом снова его раскомментить - ошибка пропадает и класс начинает работать, но ошибка появляется снова при запуске Сomposer update.

Файлы

ControlPanel.php:

```
namespace App\ICatcher\Builder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class ControlPanel extends Response {    
    public function index(){
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>TEST! BUNDLE!!</body></html>'
        );
    }    
}
```

Основной файл bundle:

```
namespace App\ICatcher\Builder;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class Builder extends Bundle
{
}
```

Composer:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "App\\ICatcher\\Builder\\":"src/ICatcher/Builder/"
        }
    },
```

bundles.php:

```
return [
    [...]  
    App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class => ['dev' => true,'test' => true],
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется у вас лишняя запись в autoload
`"App\\ICatcher\\Builder\\":"src/ICatcher/Builder/"`  по идее по правилам наименования ваш класс и так будет доступен, а  при composer update происходит дамп autoload.php в папке vendor где, скорее всего , и происходит попытка два раза объявить один и тот же класс.

Comment: Я также задавала вопрос на английском тут, если вы хотите добавить свой ответ там тоже:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871310/cannot-declare-class-error-in-symfony-4-custom-bundle

Comment: @AnastasiaSitnina спасибо, воспользовался вашим предложением.